# How do I select which folders I want to sync on OneDrive on Windows RT?

Tags: windows-8.1, sync, onedrive, microsoft-surface

I've got an old Surface RT that I just restored to factory settings.  It's trying to set up OneDrive automatically, but I've got 900 MB of music in the cloud that I don't want to download onto this machine, though I would like my documents and pictures.  It's easy in Windows 10 to select the directories to sync, but I can't find the settings in Windows RT 8.1 anywhere.  Anyone have a clue?

Comment: The Windows RT OneDrive client has reduce functionality

Comment: Actually, I'm having trouble finding 'OneDrive' for the Windows RT 8.1 OS.  I've got the old 'SkyDrive' and I can't download Onedrive from the store.  I can't find a way to selectively turn on/off the directories.

Comment: Skydrive is OneDrive before it was renamed to OneDrive...